# Store list of pairs in one table EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, database-design, ef-code-first

I used the following **class**:

```
public class Point
{
    [Required]
    public double X { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

And the **Model** containing:

```
public List<Point> Vertices { get; set; }
```

But EF tries to create a separate table based on this message :

> EntityType 'Point' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

I'll have large number of points for related model and I think it's not optimal solution to have a separate table. **Is there a way to embed point array inside the table or am I thinking wrong?**

Highly appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to show the code of the entire Model or just create a property `int VerticesId {get; set;}` as a key(with [Key] attribute above)

Comment: @Inanikian The problem is that EF wanna create a separate table for `Point` since needs `Key`, I know with adding `Key` property, the problem will be solved, but I don't know is this a optimal solution for my case or not.

Comment: From Database side the key will be optimal for queries(CRUD). Don't forget that you are using I guess a relational Database.

Comment: @Inanikian I use relational DB but don't need to have relation for points. I need them in one entry.

Comment: I don't know if You can also convert to the points to an array of byte. But I am not sure if it is optimal to convert or do the reverse array to point. Just a hint.

Comment: @Inanikian Thanks for your valued time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work - not sure if I would recommend this approach (as I think a table for point would be ok) but having said that it did seem to work for me. So I use the VerticeDataText to store the point data in a string, so it is stored in the DB:

```
public class Vertice
{
    public int VerticeID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Point[] Data
    {
        get
        {
            string[] rawInternalData = this.VerticeDataText.Split(';');
            Point[] dataResult = new Point[rawInternalData.Length / 2];
            int count = 0;
            rawInternalData.ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                var pairArray = p.Split(',');
                dataResult[count++] = new Point { X = double.Parse(pairArray[0]), Y = double.Parse(pairArray[1])};
            });
            return dataResult;
        }
        set
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            value.ToList().ForEach(p => sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1};", p.X, p.Y));
            this.VerticeDataText = sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string VerticeDataText { get; set; }
}
```